# Phonegap facebook authentication issue secirity warning

Tags: android, ios, facebook, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm building an Ionic phonegap mobile app. I'm trying to implement FB authentication.

I saw this tutorial for Ionic and I am trying to integrate FB authentication the same way:

http://ccoenraets.github.io/ionic-tutorial/ionic-facebook-integration.html

I have both urls added in my FB application settings:

```
http://localhost:5000/oauthcallback.html
https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html
```

When I test in the browser or using android emulator, everything is fine.
When I test on my phone I receive an error:

```
security warning please treat the url above as you would your password and do not share it with anyone.
```

I read everything in google but still can't find a solution.

Comment: Is any js you have passing your fb appid?

Comment: yes, I use openfb and then initialize it: 'openFB.init({appId: 'YOUR_FB_APP_ID'});' from the link above.